# I designed a algorithm and implemented code , but I do not know the time complexity of the code T(n)=O(??)

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, divide-and-conquer

1. I used so many for loops to get closet lower and larger elements, so I felt a little bit difficult to analysis the time complexity of this code.
2. I defined a function named FindClosetLagerAndLower, input a array, as results it will return two arrays named L,R respectively. L stores the index of closet lower value for each element.R stores the index of closet larger value for each element.

Comment: This looks like O(n^2) at first glance. Your loops contain at most another loop that always have under len(Array) iterations.

Comment: Your edits have fundamentally changed the code you're asking about, by cutting out an additional loop within the one that remains. There's absolutely no reason to expect two nested loops to run in n log n time rather than n^2 time unless you're doing something fancy to *ensure* that some of the times through the loops get skipped.

Answer (score 0):

normal-O(n^2)
best case- O(n^2)